# JS Auto click without using .click()

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to click something that doesn't have a click function but instead has a mouseup function. Is there anyway to do this? thx. I'm currently using:

```
document.getElementById('click').click();
```

I want to click this:

```
<button id="click" onmouseup="javascript:ack(true);" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: Just call `ack(true)` in your function instead of trying to invoke it trough the `mouseup` event?

Comment: @DarkBee How would I go about doing so?

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ack(true); });`

Comment: You need some clarity in your question... but from what I understand you want the <button> tag to have two event listeners (triggers) one being the "onmouseup" and the other a "click"?

Comment: Why would you have a mouseup handler on a button?